# jquery mobile loading image not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<title>a</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.mobile.loading('show');});
</script>
```

But the beautiful spinner image is not showing.It just shows a grey circle in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax is off, to display a loading message you should use [$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html) Also make sure you have the images folder included.

Edit:

Sorry I see that you are using the alpha of JQM 1.2, it looks like the `$.mobile.loading` method was added in this release. At any rate make sure that you have the JQM images folder and that it is located in the same folder as the js file. To test try replacing your links with links to the CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the problems comes with the stylesheet. once i use local files it won't show the spinning image even if i copy the file directly from website. The problems goes as soon as i fetch the css file from online source

Comment: Are you sure you have your paths set up correctly? A good way to check would be to look in the network tab of a web debugger (either firebug or web inspector for chrome or safari or dragonfly for opera) and see the actual path it's requesting.